# Httplib2 Grab The Source Code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, httplib, httplib2

Is there any way of grabbing the html source code from here?  I'm sending a post login request to a website, and if the response status is 302 I want to check the source code.  I couldn't find away to do this.  Here is what I have:

```
    http = httplib2.Http()
    url = "http://example.com"
    login = "test"
    password = "test"
    body = {'login': login, 'password' : password}
    headers = {'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))

    if response.status == '302':
        break
```

"break" is where I need to get the html source code.

Comment: Are you sure there is a body to "grab"?  I don't recall ever seeing a 302 with a body (unless it was trying to target browsers that don't honor a 302 and includes some html with a meta refresh tag.)

Comment: Not necessarily grabbing the body with httplib, but grab the body without having to login using something else?

Comment: Where does the location header in the 302 response take you?  Is that what happens during a successful login?

Comment: Yes, when it gets 302 it logins successfully.  When it gets 200 it fails.

Comment: So, read the location header, and open the request to wherever it points you.  The one thing is you will have to keep track of your cookies.